# can i get my sprint s3 flashed to boost mobile or verizon prepaid?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, samsung-galaxy-note-2, samsung-galaxy-s-3-mini

Wanting to know if anyone can flash my sprint s3 s4 note2 to verizon prepaid or boost mobiles unlimited plan?

Comment: What do you mean by boosting the mobile's/device's unlimited plan? Are you on limited plan right now?

Comment: @geffchang Your edit doesn't make sense. "Boost Mobile" is the name of a carrier. It's nothing to do with boosting a device or a plan.

Comment: @DanHulme Thanks for the reversal. I had no idea. Boost Mobile should have been in proper case.

Comment: Yeah, it confused me too at first; I only worked it out because I've heard of Boost Mobile from another question. Everyone, this is why capitalizing proper nouns is important!

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to flash a Verizon ROM on a Sprint phone, because Sprint and Verizon are different CDMAs. You flash a Verizon ROM on a Verizon phone, and a Sprint ROM on a Sprint phone.